# Issue starting video on iPhone with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iphone, video

im using the following piece of code to start a video with jQuery:

```
$('#game-video')[0].play();
```

This works fine in desktop browsers and most Android browsers, but the video does not start on iPhones. I have tried on different iOS versions with browserstack and they all fail to play the video?

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Basically iOS disables autoplay, so audio files can only be loaded from a user-triggered touch (click) event. Is this your case?

Comment: Well i use a plugin called draggabiliy, were i on "dragEnd" want to play the video. So it is some sort of touch event but not really a click event. http://draggabilly.desandro.com/